# How to remove symbol markers from only selected series in JavaFx Charts?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, linechart, javafx-css

I am using 4 different series in JavaFx charts. Three series are static and display various alert levels of the actual data such as Green, Yellow and Red.

I wish to display symbols as tooltips but only on actual data line(blue one) and wish to remove them from my static alert level lines(red, yellow and green) for an appealing look.

I tried using JavaFx Css but it didnt go accordingly.
Below is my code :

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { 
    -fx-stroke: #00cc33;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;        
    -fx-symbol-visible: false;
}

.default-color1.chart-series-line {

    -fx-stroke: #ffff00;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;
    -fx-symbol-visible: false;
 }

.default-color2.chart-series-line { 
    -fx-stroke: #cc0000;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;
    -fx-symbol-visible: false;
 }

.default-color3.chart-series-line{
    -fx-stroke-width: 1px;
    -fx-symbol-visible: true; 
 }
```

Below is the pictorial representation of the same :

[image]

I dont know where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for your problem. You can find all symbols on chart. Those symbols are Node (StackPane) so you can, set property visible. Here is the loop:

```
    //in loop take all series
for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {

  if (series.getName().equals("blue")) //if Name is "blue" then continue
    continue;

  //for all series, take date, each data has Node (symbol) for representing point
  for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
    // this node is StackPane
    StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) data.getNode();
    stackPane.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

And here is code example aplication:

```
public class Chart extends Application {

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("green"); //i added name to all series, to find easy in loop
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 2));

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("yellow");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 3));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 3));

    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("red");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 4));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 4));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 4));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 4));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 4));

    XYChart.Series series4 = new XYChart.Series();
    series4.setName("blue");
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 5));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 5));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 5));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 5));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 5));

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4);

    //in loop take all series
    for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {

      if (series.getName().equals("blue")) //if Name is "blue" then continue
        continue;

      //for all series, take date, each data has Node (symbol) for representing point
      for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
        // this node is StackPane
        StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) data.getNode();
        stackPane.setVisible(false);
      }
    }

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(lineChart);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 800, 600);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/resources/chart.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

And CSS:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: #00cc33;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;
}

.default-color1.chart-series-line {

    -fx-stroke: #ffff00;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;
 }

.default-color2.chart-series-line {
    -fx-stroke: #cc0000;
    -fx-stroke-type: centered;
 }

.default-color3.chart-series-line{
    -fx-stroke-width: 1px;
 }
```

Now it's look like this:
[image]

Comment: Fantastic ! I really appreciate the effort you put in ... Thank you very much for coming back and answering this :)